# Opposite of Heat Capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Like amount of energy required to increase temperature of by 1C, what is opposite to decrease temperature by 1C? I don't understand, and I might be saying something stupid tbh, but whatever.

Comment: The specific heat capacity is the amount of energy needed to **change** the temperature of an object by one Kelvin per gram of material. Whether that change up- or downward is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Still the heat capacity. The heat capacity is also the emount of energy released when the object cools by 1 K.

Conservation of energy applies, if there were any difference in the definition of heat capacity for upward and downward temperature movements then you could use the energy from cooling an object by 1 K to heat an identical object by more than 1 K and then repeat the cycle indefinitely. Clearly this isn't allowed!

Comment: I don't understand how it works

Comment: @burner8268 Under certain conditions, we have that $C=\Delta Q/\Delta T$ and thus $\Delta T = \Delta Q/C$. Now assuming $C>0$, we can have two non-trivial cases: $\Delta T>0$ and thus $\Delta Q >0$ or vice versa, which means that in order to increase the temperature, you have to put energy into the system, i.e. heat it. Conversely, if $\Delta T<0$, then $\Delta Q<0$ or vice versa, which means that the body cools by releasing heat into the environment. From that you can see that the change of temperature by $1K$ requires the same (absolute) amount of energy.

Comment: @burner8268 if you heat it up, it takes a certain amount of heat energy. If you take the heat energy out again, it cools down again.

Comment: @burner8268 Gasoline is \$6 per gallon (let's say. We have public transport here so I don't drive). That means if I buy a gallon it costs \$6. How much money do I *save* if I *don't* buy a gallon?